# Do first, think later!

Tags: riddle, word

I asked my cousin where he's studying. He didn't answer directly, but said some random sentences.

> *You love taking photographs, then you're much nearer.*
> *Do first, think later!*
> *You're looking for an animal and a vehicle.*

Could you find where my cousin is studying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your cousin is in

> Oxford

You love taking photographs, then you're much nearer.

> I think this hints towards the Radcliffe Camera which is a building.

Do first, think later!
You're looking for an animal and a vehicle.

> Close to Radcliffe Camera is the Ox+Ford University

Comment: Excellent! ....

Comment: rot13(Va n qvpgvbanel, qb pbzrf orsber guvax naq ....Bksbeq qvpgvbanel)

Comment: @Ak. ahh Clever :)

Answer (score 2):

> Think the answer is Cameroon

You love taking photographs, then you're much nearer.

> This a clue for Camera. If you love taking photographs the word camera is more likely to be on your mind and so you are much closer to guessing the country because Cameroon and Camera share the first two syllables and sound alike.

Do first, think later!

> This is a clue for the city DOuala in Cameroon. Do is the first two letters. It is also the largest city and the. Economic Captial maybe the word first also implies this.

You're looking for an animal and a vehicle.

> You can use the letters in the word Cameroon to make the words RACOON and CAR.

Comment: Nice(+1)! But it's not the intended answer... You're right with the camera part

Comment: I mean camera is the clue, but it doesn't get included in the name of that place